# The signature of a permutation

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $S_n$ denote the group of permutations on $n$ symbols. For a fixed pair $1\leq l<m\leq n$ and consider the subset
$$S_n(l,m)=\{\sigma\in S_n: \sigma(1)=l, \sigma(2)=m\}.$$
Then $S_n(l,m)$ can be identified with the group $S_{n-2}$ (right?).

Now if I pick an element $\sigma\in S_n(l,m)$ it will corresponds to a unique element $\tau \in S_{n-2}$. The question is how do I relate the signature of $\sigma$ with the signature of $\tau$? I was hoping that the signature of $\tau$ will depend on $l$ and $m$ (actually what I had in mind is that $\text{sgn}(\tau)=(-1)^{l+m}\text{sgn}(\sigma))$ but I'm not quite sure how to start proving this.

Comment: The signature of a permutation of a finite set does not depend on the labelling of the set.  That should help.

Comment: @orangeskid so it means that $\text{sgn}(\tau)=\text{sgn}(\sigma)$?

Comment: Let's see, is the above you defined a subgroup?  You do have a subgroup of permutations that fix pointwise elements in a subset. Then yes, the signatures are the same.

Comment: $S_n(l,m)$ is not a subgroup of $S_n$ when $(l,m)\neq (1,2)$ because it does not contain the identity map.

Comment: Here is something interesting: say we have two totally ordered finite sets and a bijection between them. There the bijection has a well defined signature.  But here is the thing: take a bijection $\phi$  of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$, $I \subset \{1, \ldots, n\}$, $J = \phi(I)$. Then between $I$ and $J$ we have a bijection, and so between their complements. Both have some signature, and so does (big) $\phi$. Question: what is the connection between their signatures ( it has to do with Laplace expansion of a determinant).

Comment: @durianice sorry I miss the identity. I'll edit it!

Comment: Let $G \le S_n$ be the pointwise stabilizer of $\{1,2\}$. Then $G \cong S_{n-2}$ and the sign map restricted to $G$ is again the sign map. Your set $S_n(l,m)$ is the coset $\pi G$, where $\pi$ is any permutation such that $\pi(1) = l$ and $\pi(2) = m$. Almost always you can take $\pi$ to be even. Now for $\tau \in G$ we obviously have $\mathrm{sgn}(\pi\tau) = \mathrm{sgn}(\pi) \mathrm{sgn}(\tau)$.

Comment: @orangeskid that's interesting.

Answer (score 2):

As in my comment, $S_n(l,m)$ is not a subgroup of $S_n$ when $(l,m)\neq (1,2)$.$\newcommand{\sgn}{\text{sgn}}$
The formula $\sgn(\tau)=(-1)^{l+m}\sgn(\sigma)$ is definitely wrong
because if you swap $l$ and $m$,
the $\sgn(\sigma)$ changes,
but $\sgn(\tau)$ does not change.
Try $(n,l,m)=(3,1,2)$ and $(n,l,m)=(3,2,1)$.

The most natural identification (though not necessarily a group isomorphism) from $S_n(l,m)$ to $S_{n-2}$
is simply $\sigma\mapsto \sigma|_{\{3,\dots,n\}}$.
Denote this map by $\varphi$.

Denote by $N(\sigma)$ the number of inversions of $\sigma$.
Denote by $M_\sigma(i)$ the number $$|\{(i,j):i< j\le n, \sigma(i)>\sigma(j)\}|.$$
For all $\sigma\in S_n(l,m)$, we have
$$
N(\sigma)=M_\sigma(1)+M_\sigma(2)+N(\varphi(\sigma)).
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sgn(\varphi(\sigma))=(-1)^{M_{\sigma}(1)+M_{\sigma}(2)}\sgn(\sigma).
$$

Answer (score 2):

The exact signature depends on the bijection you use. Depending on the bijection you will either have $sgn(\sigma)=sgn(\tau)$ or $sgn(\sigma)=-sgn(\tau)$.

One particularly simple bijection gives:
$sgn(\tau)=sgn(\sigma)(-1)^{1(l=1)+1(m=2)+1(l=2,m=1)}$

For this bijection, define a permutation $\alpha$ which swaps $1,l$ and $2,m$. Then, identifying $S_{n-2}$ as a subset of $S_n$ permuting $3,\dots,n$ gives a bijection by $\tau=\alpha \sigma$. The signature of alpha gives a transposition if $1$ is swapped with something else, another for $2$, and double counts if those two are the same when $l=2$ and $m=1$.

Comment: Is there a bijection such that $\text{sgn}(\tau)=(-1)^{l+m+1}\text{sgn}(\sigma)$?

Comment: I think I got it! the bijection exists, based on the cases whether $l+m+1$ is even or odd we can choose the bijection accordingly.

Comment: Just add any random transposition between elements other than 1,2,l,m to $\alpha$ and you’ll get a new bijection of the opposite sign. If you make whether you add it depend on $l,m$, then you can get any function of $l,m$ that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ any finite set. The every $\phi\colon M\to M$ has a well defined signature.  For instance, decompose $\phi$ into a product of disjoint cycles. Then $\operatorname{sign}(\phi)$ is $1$ or $-1$, depending whether the number of even cycles is even, or odd

$3$ E mnemonic: $\bf{E}$ven number of $\bf{E}$ven cycles is $\bf{E}$ven.

(Yes, a cycle of odd length is even and the other way around. To dispel the mystery, recall that a cycle of length $\ell$, raised to power $\ell$ is the identity. So a cycle of odd length, at an odd power is the identity. So it must be even.)

---

Now, let $M$, $N$ finite sets and $\phi\colon M \to N$. Then the signature of $\phi$ is not defined ( notice that $M$ and $N$ are not the same).

However, assume that moreover, $M$, $N$ are totally ordered sets, and $\phi$ a bijection from $M$ to $N$. Then the signature of $\phi$ can be defined. How? Well both $M$, $N$ are order isomorphic ( uniquely) to some $\{1,\ldots, m\}$. So now $\phi$ is like a bijection from $\{1, \ldots, m\}$ to itself, so it has a signature.

---

Now, we come to the most interesting part: how to get the signature of a permutation from its "pieces". What do we mean by that. Say $M$ is a finite totally ordered set ( you can think $M= \{1, \ldots, n\}$).  Let $\phi \colon M \to M$ a bijection. Consider its signature. Ok, no problem.  But now do this.  Take $I$ a subset of $M$ ( non-void), $I'$ its complement,  and let $J = \phi(I)$, $J'$ its complement.  Then we have the bijections

$$\phi_{\mid I} \colon I \to \phi(I)= J \\
\phi_{\mid I'} \colon I' \to \phi(I')= J'$$

So now we have three maps $\phi$, $\phi_{\mid I}$ and $\phi_{\mid I'}$.  Recall that from above, we have a well defined signature of the latter two. OK, what is the relation between them?  There is a very nice formula as follows:

$$\operatorname{sign}( \phi) = \epsilon (I,J) \cdot \operatorname{sign}( \phi_{\mid I})\cdot \operatorname{sign}( \phi_{\mid I})$$

The only thing not clear above is $\epsilon (I, J)$.  That involves the parity of the disturbance between $I$ and $J$, and is obtained as follows: say the ranks of the elements of $I$ ( in the ordered set $M$) are $i_1$, $\ldots$, $i_k$, and the ranks of the elements of $J$ are $j_1$, $\ldots$, $j_k$. Then

$$\epsilon(I,J) = (-1)^{\sum_{s=1}^k (i_s + j_s)}$$

---

I should add that this is exactly the ingredient in the [Laplace expansion of a determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion).

---

Let's give an example. Consider the permutation

$$\phi\colon \ \ \ \left( \begin{matrix} 1&\color{red}{2}&\color{red}{3}&4&5&6&\color{red}{7}&8&9&\color{red}{10} \\ 
10 &\color{red}{1}& \color{red}{8}& 5 &7 &6 &\color{red}{3}& 4 &9& \color{red}{2}\end{matrix}\right)$$

Take $I = \{2, 3, 7,10 \}$, $J=\phi(I) = \{ 1, 8, 3, 2\}$,  $I' = \{ 1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9\}$, $J'= \{ 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10\}$, and the permutations are

\begin{eqnarray}
\phi_{\mid I}\ \ \  &\colon& \left( \begin{matrix} 2& 3& 7& 10 \\ 1& 8& 3& 2 \end{matrix} \right ) \\
\phi_{\mid I'}\ \ \  &\colon& \left ( \begin{matrix} 1&4&5&6&8&9 \\10&5&7&6&4&9 \end{matrix} \right ) 
\end{eqnarray}

Now, one has to "translate" $\phi_{\mid I}$,$\phi_{\mid I'}$, into permutations of $\{1,2,3,4\}$, and $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ as follows:

\begin{eqnarray} 
\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 2& 3& 4 \\
                      1& 4 & 3 & 2 \end{matrix} \right ) , \left( \begin{matrix} 1&2&3 &4 & 5 & 6 \\ 6&2&4&3&1&5 \end{matrix} \right) 
\end{eqnarray}

Now the first one above is the transposition $(2,4)$, odd, the second one is $(3,4)\cdot ( 1,6,5)$, odd again.

Let us calculate $\epsilon(I, J)$. We have $2+3+7+10 + 1+2+3+8$ even, so it is $1$.  According to this, the signature of $\phi$ should be $(-1) \cdot (-1) \cdot 1 = 1$. Is that correct? The cycle decomposition of $\phi$ is $(1,10,2) \cdot (3,8,4,5,7)$, $0$ Even cycles so Even.  Yes!